# Microsoft Graph API operation timedout in a server

Tags: c#, .net

we are using Microsoft Graph apis for reading / sending mails from our Dotnet application. The application is working fine from DEV server. After deploying same application in PROD server, we are getting below error:

Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The operation timed out'.

Not able to find proper solutions. Please help if encountered similar type of issue. Thank you.

Comment: You have a front end which is a connection from a client to server. The backend is a connection to a database.  The connection to the database timeout.  Check you connection string.   There are two reasons this normally happens 1) The secure connection uses TLS and the TLS fails.  Often this happens with older OS IIS server that doesn't support the newer encryption algorithms in the certificate.  Also make sure the certificate is loaded. 2) There is no route to the server in the connection string.  Timeouts occur when the server isn't running, a route doesn't exist to the server, or TLS fails